# Spring WS SOAP Request set signature reference URI's

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws

Need to add Custom Reference URI values to my SignedInfo and SecurityTokenReference.

Using Spring-WS and Spring-WS-Security and have created a SOAP Client that consists of mutual authentication, address header and setting of the binary security token and signature... all generates fine... except the Service provider requires me to set Reference URI to a specific value and not of the one the framework sets up.

I'm not sure how it can be done? I'm Using Wss4jSecurityInterceptor to create the signatures etc, but not sure how to define the specific URI's.

I do have a custom ClientInterceptor and I thought that perhaps I could do it there, but not sure if that's possible either.

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-81fb309">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
               <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                  <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="SOAP-ENV wsa" />
               </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
               <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
               <ds:Reference URI="#id-29b0d50b-caa1-422a-b90d-bb6543300ff1">
                  <ds:Transforms>
                     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                  </ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                  <ds:DigestValue>gqH/tJW0lrWqkuugE8cUgkK3ofk=</ds:DigestValue>
               </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>abcdefg</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-624f4c36-5">
               <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-b426">
                  <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-74d2f26b-6e2b-4c07-b290-d4e71a94cd21" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />
               </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
```

So from above need to set custom `<ds:Reference/>` and  `<wsse:Reference/>` URI's

ds:Reference URI="MYCUSTOMURI" and 
wsse:Reference URI="MYCUSTOMURI"